# Using native framework with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

What is the best way to add one of Apple's native frameworks, (e.g. Quick Look Framework) to a Cocoapods managed Xcode project/workspace?

Note that I want to link to that framework **directly**, and not through another pod dependency.

Obviously I could add that framework to `Build Phases` for each target, but I'm guessing there's another better way like adding required frameworks to Podfile, or...

Any thoughts?

Comment: to my knowledge, if you enable "Link Frameworks automatically" in the build settings (on by default), you do not have to link native frameworks anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as [@Palle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557145/palle) suggested in a comment:

> If you enable "Link Frameworks automatically" in the build settings (on by default), you do not have to link native frameworks anymore.

Thanks